# Вывод строк из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql

Строка хранится БД, что-то вроде:

> ЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫ ЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫ
> ЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫ

При показе ее выводит в одну строку, а желательно бы, чтоб хоть как-то изменял, например:

> ыыыыыыыыыыыыыыы
> ыыыыыыыыыыыыыыы
> ыыыыыыыыыыыыыыы
> ыыыыыыыыыыыыыыы

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3):

[wordwrap](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php):

```
$text = "ЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫЫ";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 8, " ", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите strlen (подсчет количества символов) и пробел

```
function probel($stroka)
{
    $colvo = strlen($stroka);
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $colvo; $i++) {
        if ($j == 15) {
            $mass .= " ";
            $j = 0;
        } else {
            $mass .= $stroka[$i];
            $j++;
        }
    }
    return $mass;
}

$a = probel('ssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss');
print "a - $a<br>";
```

Готовый пример. |^|

Comment: Кстати размер кусков зависит от ша($j==число){}

Comment: Вы меня не поняли.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo nl2br($text);
```

Другое не приходит в голову...

Answer (score 0):

В этом случае, для веб разработки, наиболее приемлимо не строку ковырять а просто выставить размеры блоку в который выводится строка на странице. Если к примеру строка выводится в div и ты хочешь что бы она была "не в одну строку" то просто выстави div'у ограниченную ширину!

Answer (score 0):

если я правильно понял, то вам поможет это:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\\r\\n/','<br \/>',$string);
echo $sting
```

где $string - строка из БД